# Cross Site Collection call in SP Hosted App

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, rest

I want to read a list from one of my site collection(SiteColl A) using a SP Hosted App. This App will be deployed in another Site collection(SiteColl B) in the same web application. I know one way to achieve this is by using Tenant Scope Deployment and using `AppContextSite` object. But Tenant scope deployment will create only one App web below the App Catalog Site,which i do not want since it will be deployed in multiple site collections and each with different branding.(Will have to reconsider this if no other solution works out).

So i am trying to explore other techniques like REST call from the app to the other site collection (this is a public site with anonymous access). So i added a Script Editor webpart in my SiteCollB  and tried to read list in SiteCollA using REST service call, and it worked perfectly and gave me the data. But that same code is somehow not working in the App.

```
     $.ajax({
      url: "http://sitecollectionURL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('CommonSettings')/items",
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      },
      success: function (data) {
          console.log('success');
          $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
              console.log(item.Title);
          });
      },
      error: function (error) {
          alert('fail');
          console.log(error);
      }
  });
```

So is the App masking its restriction on to my REST call? Is there any other technique to achieve this?

Comment: What are the permissions on the app? Giving read permissions on tenant will allow you to read all items across all site collections.

Comment: I have given manage permission to tenant . read permission alone will not give permission across all site collections, it has to be a tenant scope deployed App , right?

Comment: [These](http://tinypic.com/r/dnkls6/8) are what my app's permissions look like.  It needs to edit the list items, but if it was just reading, then you can change it to read.  You will also need to use the Cross-domain library to read the list.

Comment: @wjervis agreed but after giving the permissions and using cross domain library , I would still need to deploy it as a Tenant Scope App (which i am trying to avoid and looking for another alternative if any)

Comment: Sadly i am concluding my requirement can be done only through Tenant Scope deployment. Still keeping this open so that some one can bring up some good discussion

Comment: I've never deployed any of my apps as tenant scoped apps (my apps contain app parts), and I use those permissions along with the cross-domain library.